# Web.config in virtual directory is not overriding parent website's Web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config, iis-7.5, connection-string

I've got a website which has a virtual directory that also includes a website, and when I try to launch a page from the virtual directory, I receive an IIS 7.5 error that the name (from the connection string) is already in the collection. This wasn't a problem before I added a domain user as the Identity in the app pool. Does anyone know why this is happening? I was under the impression that sub level application's web.config overrides the parent's by default. And again, this was once working until I added a custom Identity.

> The error on the page is "Parser Error Message: The entry 'dbname' has already been added."

Where the dbname is in both connection strings (i.e. parent and virtual directory). I can't delete one of the connection strings because the virtual directory is only created for test purposes, but in production it runs as its own website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sub web.config doesn't override a parent regardless of application. All web.configs will stack up all the way to the root of the primary application. In order for sub-application folder to make use of a connection string key that is already in use it must first be removed or all connection strings must be cleared. If you want this to be a truly stand alone application as a child add this to your connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <your connection string>
<connectionStrings>
```

If you just want to remove the single connection string use this:

```
<remove key="yourConnectionStringName" />
```

Comment: Any idea why this didn't happen before? I've been setting up both applications like this for years and never ran into a conflict.

Also, I can't exclude the connection string in the sub app because this is generally used at the root level of the server.

Comment: @u84six: It won't remove it for the root level, it will only remove it from the application at that level (and any children of that application). No, I honestly can't say as to why it's this sudden. The change you describe has no role in this conflict.

Comment: @MystereMan: That is not correct. A virtual directory will be considered as any normal subdirectory and the web.config files will continue to stack and inherit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @JoelEtherton how do I achieve this in IIS 6? My website is running SharePoint (2007). I created an application in a virtual directory under this website, managed by its own application pool. Yet, I am encountering conflicts between SharePoint's configuration and this application. See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/727228/virtual-directory-application-web-config-conflicting-with-sharepoint-web-config) I posted in Server Fault. The goal is to have this application in the virtual directory be completely independent of SharePoint's web.config.

Comment: @WebUser: I've commented over there on that question. However, with respect to this question, if you want them to be truly uncoupled, you'd have to look at the web.config for the SharePoint and make sure that every section that is referenced in SharePoint is dereferenced with `<clear />`. The danger in this is that you'd also be eliminating anything specified in the machine.config so you'd have to replicate those entries in your child web.config. However, looking at the symptom of your problem, the web.config is unlikely to be the culprit.

Comment: @JoelEtherton yes, using `<clear />` risks losing too much of what is provided by machine.config. Will `<remove />` be applicable in this situation? I mean, can I remove a certain portion and add it back in the ASP.NET application's web.config?

Answer (score 0):

@u84six,

Today this had happened to me.
I had some websites and webservices in the same root website. The root is the default iis website (Default Web Site) and i think it was pointing to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot. Its a development environment.

After i read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/386126), i found out that one of my webservices was the root website (still not sure what changed it... maybe visual studio after a migration from 2010 to 2012). That webservice was using the connectionString in conflict. I change the path back to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ and everything went to normal.

Maybe something similar happened to you.